# Apply a transformation with Haskell OpenGL

Tags: haskell, opengl

With Haskell OpenGL, it is possible to apply a transformation to an object like this:

```
  preservingMatrix $ do
    translate myvector
    renderObject Solid $ Sphere' 0.2 50 50
```

The transformations `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale` are available. I would like to apply the transformation corresponding to an orthonormal `3x3` matrix `M` which is not a rotation. Is it possible and how ?

Of course, as a desperate solution I could decompose `M` into translations and rotations (this is possible if I correctly remember my maths courses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is `multMatrix`. I've followed [this example](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/hopengl/2005-October/000655.html). If your matrix is

```
a b c 
d e f 
g h i
```

then do something like

```
  ......
  preservingMatrix $ do
    myTransformation
    materialDiffuse Front $= green
    renderObject Solid $ Teapot 5
  swapBuffers
  where
    myTransformation = do
      m <- (newMatrix RowMajor [ a, b, c, 0
                               , d, e, f, 0
                               , g, h, i, 0
                               , 0, 0, 0, 1]) :: IO (GLmatrix GLfloat)
      multMatrix m
```

If you want to add a translation, do

```
  m <- (newMatrix RowMajor [ a, b, c, x
                           , d, e, f, y
                           , g, h, i, z
                           , 0, 0, 0, 1]) :: IO (GLmatrix GLfloat)
```

where `(x,y,z)`is the translation vector.

[image: teapot]

Answer (score 0):

My Haskell is rusty and I've never used it with OpenGL before, but maybe you are looking for [`multMatrix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-3.0.2.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-CoordTrans.html#v:multMatrix)?

Comment: Maybe. I have seen this function but so far I have not understood how one uses it.

Comment: I've found some examples but for `4x4` matrices. I will try.

Comment: Honest question: for somebody who is familiar with OpenGL, is the documentation in that module sufficient? e.g. would you know what `ortho` does and what order to put its arguments in without source diving? (Perhaps the connection to "section 2.11 of the OpenGL 2.1 specs" is so clear that the specs clarify what this does...??)

Comment: @DanielWagner I would have never understood OpenGL without tutos and examples. The documentation is rather meager.